# Codes to automatically edit html

Tags: html, r

I have a list of HTML files. What I regularly need to do is open them in R find the end of the header section `</head>` and manually paste a given set of codes like say:

`<p>This report helps you find the critical issues in your data</p>`

Can someone help me in writing a code that automatically finds the end of the header tag and pastes the given set of lines?

The same exercise may be doable in some other tool, but please assist me for R specifically

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the `XML` page and learn about xpath queries, which help to search through HTML files. Let's say you downloaded all your files to `some_dir`, and you wanted to parse the text and find only `<p>` that were in `<div class="come_class">`.

```
library(XML)
files <- list.files("some_dir", full.names = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
docs <- lapply(files, htmlParse)

text.nodes <- 
  lapply(docs, function(doc) 
    getNodeSet(doc, '//div[@class="some_div"]//p'))

text.value <- 
  lapply(text.nodes, function(node)
            sapply(node, xmlValue))
```

Comment: pretty sure the OP wants to add text to the XML doc, too

Comment: nograpes Thanks for the reply, @hrbrmstr is true, I want to edit the html enter a line and save it. Your codes are helping me find the section, but how do I get into it and edit it?

Comment: @AnuragH the `XML` pkg has `addNode()`, `addChildren()`, `addSibling()` (etc)