# How to edit code in a html file with R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html><head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div align="left" style="height: 475px;">
    <noscript><div style="color: red; width: 30%; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif;"></div></noscript>
    <div id="x"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="x.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">x.embed("x","720px","475px","x.xml","true","false");</script>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to insert css script within the `<head></head>` and the file become this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html><head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
      body{margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color:black;}
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div align="left" style="height: 475px;">
    <noscript><div style="color: red; width: 30%; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif;"></div></noscript>
    <div id="x"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="x.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">x.embed("x","720px","475px","x.xml","true","false");</script>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone show me the steps how to do that with R?
Detailed explanation will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate, relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940179/r-codes-to-automatically-edit-html

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
library(xml2)
h <- as_list(read_html("yourfile.html"))
css <- list('body {background-color:black;}')
attr(css, "type") <- "text/css"
h$html$head$style <- css

write_html(as_xml_document(h$html), "outfile.html", 
           options=c("format","no_declaration"))
```

**outfile.html**:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">body {background-color:black;}</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I have the following problem when using your script:
Error: Root nodes must be of length 1

Comment: @ea1029 At which step ? When you run `read_html`? Did you post the exact contents of your file ?

Comment: Sorry @Stéphane Laurent I didn't show my exact contents, it contains a <body><div><script>...</script></div></body>